# Go to Range and add cells with specific value to a new range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm bit new with vba in Excel.
I'm trying to make a funtion to check a range for a specific text and add the cell containing the value to a new range. And return the new range.

I found a piece of code from brettdj on almost the same matter and alter it a bit for my situation.

The function look like:

```
Function Test(Testvalue As String, TargetRange As Range) As Range

  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim c As Range

  For Each c In TargetRange
    If c.Text = Testvalue Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        ' Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc cell to our new range, rng2
        ' this is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, c)
        Else
        ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
            Set rng2 = c
        End If
    End If
    Next
  Set Test = rng2
End Function
```

But when I put this in use in excel, for example in =IsBlank(test(Apple;A1:A5)) it returns a #VALUE!.

Has somebody an idea how i can get this to work.
Many thz in advance

Comment: What do you want the function to return? I tested the function and it returned `FALSE`, not `#VALUE!`. Do you want the function to return true/false, or do you want it to return the cell address(es) where the values were found?

Comment: Hello ARich, I want to return the cell adressess as a Range. So I can use the output in a other function what has a range as input. There is one mistake in my question I tested it with Countblank instead of IsBlank. That has the outcome #Value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cell addresses are of the `String` type, not a `Range` type, so you can't return both from the function. User Defined Functions (UDFs) cannot return Range objects. What you *can* do is return the addresses of each cell:

```
Function Test(Testvalue As String, TargetRange As Range) As String
  Dim rng2 As String
  Dim c As Range

    For Each c In TargetRange
        If c.Text = Testvalue Then
            If rng2 <> vbNullString Then
                ' Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc cell to our new range, rng2
                ' this is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)
                rng2 = rng2 & "," & c.Address
            Else
                ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
                rng2 = c.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Test = rng2
End Function
```

The output from this function is a comma-delimited list of cell addresses where the string was found. (B3 contains the formula, B2 shows what the formula in B3 looks like.)

[image: Example Usage]

To use this string of cell addresses, you'd have to create a different UDF (although a UDF cannot modify a different cell's contents or formatting):

```
Function test2(TestValue As String) As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range(TestValue)
        MsgBox "The cell's address is: " & c.Address
    Next c
    test2 = "Last calculated on " & Now()
End Function
```

If you're trying to modify in any way the cells that contain the text "Apple", you should consider using a different approach.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, I can't add single cells from a given range together and return that Rang? It will always return a comma-delimited string right?

Comment: @BasdeKoning Correct, if you're trying to return the range object via a UDF (formula) in the Excel sheet. You can do what you're talking about if you're trying to return a range via a function in a Sub procedure or function.

Comment: @BasdeKoning The code in my answer will always return a string, comma-delimited if multiple cells are found.

Answer (score 0):

additional variant to already provided

```
Function Test(Testvalue As String, TargetRange As Range) As String
  Dim d As Object: Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In TargetRange
    If c.Value2 = Testvalue Then d.Add c.Address(0, 0), ""
  Next
  Test = Join(d.keys, ","):  Set d = Nothing
End Function
```